# Database table, Should all tables require a foreign key from the user table without over normalising

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to design a database for a garage management system. And I am struggling with over normalising, Would it be best to have User_ID as a foreign key within all tables to make querying faster or does this design make sense?
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for ORM, your design is absolutely correct. There is no redundancy and data is easily reached by transitivity. Nevertheless, sometimes, development urges for simplification and better performance. Performance must prevail over design.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend adding `user_id` to the other tables.  That just seems like a maintenance nightmare -- ensuring that the `user_id` is consistent across the tables.

Instead, you might want to borrow a technique which is associated with dimensional modeling (which is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling)).  That is flattening dimensions.

This means that you would have *one* table apart from users at the most detailed level.  All the information about spaces, zones, boxes, and items would be in the same table.

This works assuming that the dimension values do not really change over time -- think time dimensions or geographic dimensions.

Comment: Just to clarify are you suggesting to make a "management table" which would then have all the ID's of the other tables relating them to each other e.g. : ID|User_ID||Space_ID||Zone_ID||Box_ID||Item_ID|| to manage them all?

Comment: @Robbie . . . I am pointing out that this as a possible alternative.  Your question doesn't have enough information to actually make a suggestion.

Comment: Also a maintenance nightmare. As soon as you begin replicating fields, downgrading your normal forms, you need to mitigate risk.